# Weblogic Bridge Message - Failure of server APACHE bridge:

Tags: apache

Here in this case, when a client is trying to access a particular URI, they are able to get a SUCCESS response for GET,  but for the POST message, they are recieving a 500 error. Which is nothing but INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

please look at the ERROR below:

Weblogic Bridge Message

### Failure of server APACHE bridge:

---

Cannot open TEMP post file '/tmp/_wl_proxy/_post_1818_8' for POST of 3978 bytes

---

Weblogic Bridge Message

### Failure of server APACHE bridge:

---

```
Internal Server failure, APACHE plugin.  Cannot continue.
```

---

Eventually this was resolved after giving a 777 permission to /tmp/_wl_proxy and the client was able to access the page SUCCESSFULLY.
If this is a permission issue, then apache should throw 403 error, but  i dont know why it was throwing 500 error.

if there is a internal server error, then both GET and POST response should be 500, So if anyone can answer this , it would be a great learning experience. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

You many not want to give Write to all (777) permission to /tmp/_wl_proxy directory.  Check which userID apache is running under and only give writer permission to that userID.

This could be also with tmp directory full.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this problem:

1. Go to weblogic management console (http://:7001/console)
2. Go to the server section, you will probably find one of your servers' status not running. This is what I found in my case;
3. Some features couldn't be run unless you have administrative privilege, I advice you stop all servers and re-run them as an administrator as you follow your servers status in the administrative console.
4. If the above doesn't work, something has to do with your either report or form server configuration is hindering the servers from starting up. In all cases you need to monitor the administration console.