# Failure of Web Server bridge

Tags: apache, weblogic

I am getting Failure of Web Server bridge, while uploading file from my application through Apache server with weblogic server.
In log,
 ***Error 13 in opening temp request body file '/var/log/httpd/apache/_wl_proxy/_post_20646_0***
But in this location (/var/log/httpd),i am not able to see any folder like apache.Even try to create folder and gave full permission with owner as apache user.But still same issue.Could you please why apache and _wl_proxy are not created automatically?Also how to solve this issue.I already tried below steps
[Weblogic Bridge Message - Failure of server APACHE bridge:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457374/weblogic-bridge-message-failure-of-server-apache-bridge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your apache instance you have some configuration for mod_wl.so. By default, "FileCaching" is enabled and any upload bigger then 2k will be buffered in a temporary file.

To solve your problem, you could try testing with "FileCaching Off" to see if the error truly is related to this temporary file buffering. If so, try adding a "WLTempDir" directive with a sane directory to force saving the temporary files elsewhere.